# No compile error for a not implemented interface

Tags: c#, interface, visual-studio-2015

at minimal strange, but i believe that exist a explanation...
I have an interface (IRepository) with 6 methods to be implemented by class. But when i put code to implement the interface, the VS2015 don't show up to me option to implement class and if i don't implement manually and compile the project it doesn't show up compile errors, shouldn't it? Should it show up compile errors tell me that i didn't implement the interface.

Interface:

```
 public interface IRepository<T> where T : class
{       
    IQueryable<T> GetAll ();
    IQueryable<T> FindBy ( Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate );
    void Add ( T entity );
    void Delete ( T entity );
    void Edit ( T entity );
    void Save ();
}
```

Class that should implements IRepository, but not implements and it doesn't throw a compile error:

```
public class GenericRepository<T> where T : class, IRepository<T>
{
}
```

Comment: After some searches in google i found the issue: It should be written like this: **`public class GenericRepository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class`**

Comment: Just like the answer written below ? `TEntity` or `T`, it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 5):

`GenericRepository` doesn't implement `IRepository`. But it accepts a Generic type parameter that is a type that implements `IRepository`.

To force `GenericRepository` to implement `IRepository` you need to use this:

```
public class GenericRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{
   // implement the interface here
}
```

Whereas if you leave the code as it is, you need to declare you object like this:

```
var repo = new GenericRepository<SomeClassThatImplementsIReporsitory>();
```